# implementation of mandatory access control in mysql

Tags: unix

HOw to implement mandatory access control in mysql. How to set the classifications (i.e top secret, secret, confidential and unclassified)  and clearances in mysql. and how to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

First can you make users in your mysql server. For example:

```
CREATE USER 'your_name'@'localhost';
```

[Here is](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-user.html) syntax refernce.

and add grants whith [GRANT statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html):

```
GRANT ALL ON your_db.* TO 'your_name'@'localhost';
```

The MySQL access-control can use for adjust who can update, select, insert data to db or who can connects from a given host and what is that user with privileges.

Note: These things are cannot do with the MySQL privilege system:

- You cannot explicitly specify that a given user should be denied access. That is, you cannot explicitly match a user and then refuse the connection.
- You cannot specify that a user has privileges to create or drop tables in a database but not to create or drop the database itself.
- A password applies globally to an account. You cannot associate a password with a specific object such as a database, table, or routine.

Please check [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privilege-system.html) for more information.